# How to Show User Current Location On Zoom When View Did Load in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am newbie in iOS Development i make an Goggle map Supported app it Shows User Current Location but When i Press CurrentLocation Button on my `GMSMapView` then i show user Current Location but i want to Show User to Current Location WithOut Button Press i mean When `viewDidLoad` i Show Direct Current Location with Zoom Please Help me.

Here i Write a code like as in my `.h File`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
@end
```

And Code for `.m File like as`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}
```

Please help me For Show Current location without Current location Button Press.
And Please Help me How to Get Current Location Address in Google map.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
[self.mapView animateToLocation: self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate];
```

Keep in mind that `myLocation` might be `nil` if the location is not determined yet! You could use Key-Value Observing (KVO) to determine when to animate to current location.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.mapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"]) {
        // Animate map to current location (This will run every time user location updates! 
        [self.mapView animateToLocation: self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate];
        // You can remove self from observing 'myLocation' to only animate once
        [self.mapView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];
    }
}
```

Comment: @thnks amrin but it is not working in simulated. and i want to get address from latitude and Longitude how it is Possible?

Comment: Here i want to Zoom DIrect to my Location It is Not Set Zoom to Direct my Location like as when i was Set Location to Mumbai in my simulater .then it is Only Show Mumbai Not A perfect Location in mumbai.Please give me solution for it.

Comment: You can use the `- (void) animateToZoom: (float) zoom` method. so set the `[self.mapView animateToZoom: zoomFloat];`

Comment: You should really read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view